# Django Query: Annotate with `count` of a *window*

Tags: database, django, django-queryset

I search for a query which is pretty similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501149/django-order-by-count-of-a-foreignkey-field). But as an extension, I do not want to count all objects, but just over the ones, that are fairly recent.

In my case, there are two models. Let one be the `Source` and one be the `Data`. As result I'd like to get a list of all `Source`s ordered by the number of data records, that has been collected during the last week. 
For me it is not iteresting, how many data records have been collected in total, but if there is a recent activity of that source.

Using the following code snippet from the above link, I cannot make up how to *subquery* the `Data` Table before.

```
from django.db.models import Count
activity_per_source = Source.objects.annotate(count_data_records=Count('Data')) \
            .order_by('-count_data_records')
```

The only ways I came up with, would be to write native SQL or to process this in a loop and individual queries. Is there a Django-Query version?

(I use a MySQL database and Django 1.5.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout out the docs on the order of annotate and filter: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses

Try something along the lines of:

```
activity_per_source = Source.objects.\
    filter(data__date__gte=one_week_ago).\
    annotate(count_data_records=Count('Data')).\
    order_by('-count_data_records').distinct()
```

Comment: this works great! I am not that familiar with the `__` yet. It seems kind of non-intuitive, that I filter over something, I have not yet annotated. Thanks anyways

Comment: I had no idea this would work, I am glad it did. The `__` of Django queries is indeed very useful, and not that intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way of doing that mixing Django queries with SQL via `extra`:

```
start_date = datetime.date.today() - 7
activity_per_source = (
    Source.objects
    .extra(where=["(select max(date) from app_data where source_id=app_source.id) >= '%s'"
           % start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')])
    .annotate(count_data_records=Count('Data'))
    .order_by('-count_data_records'))
```

The `where` part will filter the Sources by its `Data` last date.

Note: replace table and field names with actual ones.