# Calculate field and order by the calculated field

Tags: django, orm, django-1.9

I have the following models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    User = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def GetVotes(self):
        return Vote.objects.filter(Question=self).aggregate(Sum('Vote'))['Vote__sum']

class Vote(models.Model):
    Question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    User = models.ForeignKey(User)
    Vote = models.IntegerField()
```

And as can be seen from the `Question` model I use a custom method to calculate the votes for each question. I do that as I would like to separate the votes from the actual question, and hence I wouldn't want to keep a vote counter in the `Question` model as well as in `Vote` as this will be hard to maintain later.

According to good design, information that can be calculated shouldn't be stored.

I can now find the votes of each question just fine, but the problem comes down to the `order_by`. I would like to get all the questions, and order them by their votes. As far as I am aware, that is not possible as the `order_by()` is down to the database level, where my method is not at a database level.

I would like to find a nice way to do that without using other technique than `ORM` is that possible?

Edit:
It looks like there is no nice way using ORM so I have implemented using `sorted`.

Comment: I thin annotate should do what you want, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501149/order-by-count-of-a-foreignkey-field?rq=1

Comment: Thank you for your comment @ger.s.brett. I have faced this solution, before asking the question, but the only difficulty I found with this solution is that there should be a `join` between the two models so that I can achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that since order_by is applied at database level.

But you have two alternatives:

1. Create a field to store the calculated value and override write method so that you can calculate the value there
2. Sort the queryset as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981375/using-a-django-custom-model-method-property-in-order-by/981802#981802)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was thinking of a `view` table instead of storing the data in the `Question` model, but I am not sure if that is possible with Django.

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate the data you're looking to sort on and then sort by that value.

`Question.objects.annotate(vote_count=Sum('vote_set__vote')).order_by('vote_count')`