# Django order by issue

Tags: django

I don't know how to do to order by in this situation. May be someone knows.

I have 2 models :

Comments :

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=False)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path_comments, validators=[validate_file_extension], blank=True, null=True)
    articles = models.ForeignKey(Articles, verbose_name="Article", null=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Auteur")
    in_answer_to = models.ForeignKey('self', verbose_name="En réponse au commentaire", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, verbose_name="Date de création")
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Dernière modification")
```

And a Up model :

```
class Up(models.Model):
    comments = models.ForeignKey(Comments, verbose_name="Commentaire", null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Auteur", null=False)
```

Users can add comments and they can "Up" some usefull comments.

So, by default I want to order comments by date. However I want to priorize the order by number of Up.

To give you an idea how comments and Up are register, this is a screenshot of my database :

Comments :
[image]

Up :
[image]

For example, the comment where id is 50 has 2 Up from two differents users. So it should be at top of the list compared to the comment 49 which only have 1 Up.

For now, I just use the order by date and I need the order by Up :

```
comments = Comments.objects.all().exclude(in_answer_to__isnull=False).order_by('-date')
```

I need something like :

```
comments = Comments.objects.all().exclude(in_answer_to__isnull=False).order_by('-date', 'Up')
```

Comment: Have you seen [Order by count of a ForeignKey field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2501178/4974980)?

Comment: I didn't know about this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order by count of a ForeignKey field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501149/order-by-count-of-a-foreignkey-field)

Comment: @Jens Astrup,  what the OP want is order by a reverse relationship, not by foreignkey

Comment: @JoseCherian Did you look at the question I linked to, or just the title?

Comment: @Jens Astrup, sorry, I was fooled by the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you think about SQL for the following order problem, you would find out that you probably need to count number of referred objects

so annotate count and order by it

```
comments = Video.objects.all().exclude(
    in_answer_to__isnull=False
).annotate(
    num_up=Count('up')
).order_by('-date', 'num_up')
```

Comment: Thanks, It's something like that.