# Home page layout

Tags: python, django

I am creating a blog website with Django. I want to get the number of comments in a single Post (i have a whole dictionary of posts that can be called) as an int and use it in the following def:

```
def top_three(request)
    first = -1
    second = -1
    third = -1
    com = Comment.objects.filter(approved_comment)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(comments__in=com)
    for post in posts:
        if len(posts) >= 3:
            postvar = len(com)
            if postvar > first:
                first = postvar
                one = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
            elif postvar > second:
                second = postvar
                two = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
            elif postvar > third:
                third = postvar
                three = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
        else:
            return render(request, 'blog/home.html')
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', {
        'one': one,
        'two': two,
        'three': three,
    })
```

Assume that i have imported everything that needs to be imported

The Comment model is directly relateble to the Post model, a person cannot have a comment without a relevant post. My models are:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    url = models.TextField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    discription = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def approved_comments(self):
        return self.comments.filter(approved_comment=True)
```

And

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', related_name='comments')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

How do you suggest that I call one, two and three in the blog/home.html?

Comment: This doesn't make sense unless there is a relation between `ModelOne` and `ModelTwo`. Please post your actual models instead of a hypothetical case.

Comment: I have made it a bit clearer now

Comment: Can you share your models.py? I think you want to filter all Comments by Posts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501149/order-by-count-of-a-foreignkey-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want each Posts which has comments approved, do

```
com = Comment.objects.filter(approved=True)
my_var = Post.objects.filter(comments__in=com)
```

Comment: It gives me a FieldError Cannot resolve keyword 'Comment' into field

Comment: Try doing Post.objects.filter(comments__in=com), the related_name parameter in your class Comment means that you've to call it that way

Comment: After fixing the typo it still didn't work, i think i must rephrase my whole question.

Comment: I have retested your answer and it partially, but there is something wrong with my home.html. Thank you for helping.