# model obj is returning same object

Tags: django, django-models

Hope you are fine

i have 2 models

```
class Property(models.Model):
    ....
    city = models.ForeignKey(City,on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class City(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='city/img',blank=True,null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)
```

i want to get 3 cities which has most count of properties means i want cities which has most properties

so i use this query:

```
city = City.objects.all().order_by("-property")[0:3]
```

but this is not working, because it's returning same value

here is the output:

```
<QuerySet [<City: lahore>, <City: lahore>, <City: lahore>]>
```

lahore has the highest count of properties so it's giving me only lahore

i want three cities for example city1 , city2 , city3 with highest count of properties

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order by count of a ForeignKey field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501149/order-by-count-of-a-foreignkey-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This output means you have at least 3 city objects named 'lahore' in your db, try merging/ deleting some of them.
also try using this in your queryset:

```
cities = City.objects.all().annotate(num_properties=Count('property')) \
                .order_by('-num_properties')[:3]
```

Comment: name 'Count' is not defined

Comment: i have only 1 entry in db

Comment: then import it:
`from django.db.models import Count`