# How to order a queryset using related_name in django

Tags: python, django, sql-order-by, filtering, django-queryset

I've got a User model which is related to the DriverCar model using related_name='driver'. Each user could be related to multiple drivercars. DriverCar model has a field "`reference_number`" of type integer. I want to show a list of all users ordered by the`reference_number` of the last DriverCar object related to the user. Using a query like  `User.objects.filter(archive=False).order_by('-driver__reference_number')` gives me the wrong answer. But if I use `order_by('-pk')` everything works perfectly. Is there any way to do this correctly?

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    archive = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class DriverCar(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User , on_delete=models.CASCADE , related_name='driver')
    reference_number = models.BigIntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will combine from a couple of existing answers to other questions...

You will need a [subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) to get the value of `reference_number` for the "last DriverCar object related to the user."

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60217311/202168

I'm assuming "last" can mean "highest pk" (of DriverCar)

So the subquery will look like:

```py
subquery = (
    Subquery(
        DriverCar.objects.filter(user_id=OuterRef("id")
    )
    .order_by("-pk")
    .values('reference_number')[:1]
)
```

We can [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) our User queryset with the value from the subquery like:

```py
User.objects.filter(archive=False).annotate(last_driver_reference_number=subquery)
```

Then we should be able to sort on the annotated field, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1396313/202168

So:

```py
qs = (
    User
    .objects
    .filter(archive=False)
    .annotate(last_driver_reference_number=subquery)
    .order_by("last_driver_reference_number")
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked just perfectly. It's just I want the ordering to be descending. Ascending order works just fine, but when I try to make it descending by using `.order_by("-last_driver_reference_number")` it doesn't work. is there any solution for that?

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: It gives me the wrong answer. the result doesn't have a specific order. @anentropic

Comment: are you saying that if you look at the values of `last_driver_reference_number` field in the result set it's not ordered by that?